# Powershell/CMD command to open IE10 in compatibility mode

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, powershell, compatibility

I am looking for a powershell command to open Internet Explorer 10 in compatibility mode
like

`C:\Program files(x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe www.abc.com` opens www.abc.com in IE10.

I want to open the same site in IE8, IE9 (compatibility modes of IE10) as well through powershell. Is there any IE parameter/hack to accomplish this ?

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: are you having IE10 specific issues of specific pages that you are trying to test the compatibility of?

Comment: @soandos, It opens abc.com in IE10

Comment: @txtechhelp, i have made some web pages and i just want to see how they looks in IE8, IE9 and i want to do it from powrshell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It is MS's compatibility toolkit. Sounds like what you might need as there is not a direct way to enable compatibility mode from the command line (which is what you would need to do if running from a command window or powershell).

Take a look at [this answer too](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/how-can-i-test-my-web-site-in-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-ie9) as it provides more detailed info on what it sounds like you're trying to accomplish.

Hope that helps.